# Location icon is not showing on the google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, user-interface

```js
window.onload = function initmap() {
  var styles = [{
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#2b2b2b"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "on"
    }, {
      "color": "#333333"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "on"
    }, {
      "color": "#808080"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }, {
      "color": "#808080"
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#5d5d5d"
    }, {
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#5d5d5d"
    }, {
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#808080"
    }, {
      "visibility": "on"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }];
  var options = { // googel map with javascript
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
    },
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.786254, -85.428930),
    zoom: 16,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: 'Styled'
  };
  var div = document.getElementById('surabaya');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: 'Styled'
  });
  map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);


  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 41,
      lng: -85
    }
  });
  var image = 'images/marker.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 41.786254,
      lng: -85.428930
    },
    map: map1,
    icon: image
  });
};
```

```css
#surabaya {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="surabaya"></div>
```

I want to editing in the google map i have successfully changed the styling. Now i want to show the location marker of my choice . I am unable to set the icon of my choice and i am also not getting the default icon marker of the google map.i Have attached all my codes and i have also attached the google map api script and have entered my own API-KEY in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try This .. it should helps you sure ..
use your **base_url()** path for markerimage.

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/marker.png");
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: {
   lat: 41.786254,
   lng: -85.428930
 },
 map: map1,
 icon: image
});
```